# Scraping web data to form dataframe in R

Tags: html, r, dataframe, web-scraping

I am trying to import data from this website as a dataframe for further analysis in R.
https://www.forbes.com/powerful-brands/list/#tab:rank_header:position

I need only the table provided here.
Here's the code I've used:

```
htmlcontent=getURL("https://www.forbes.com/powerful-brands/list/#tab:rank", 
ssl.verifypeer= FALSE)
htmlparsed=htmlTreeParse(htmlcontent, useInternal= TRUE)
output=unlist(xpathApply(htmlparsed, '//td', xmlValue))
```

This only gives the column headings. None of the data gets scraped. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at the rvest package? Might be helpful. What libraries are you currently using? It doesn't look like base.

Comment: I suspect that the page uses some cunning Javascript tricks designed to prevent scraping. Take a look at the page source; you'll see the table header but no rows.

Comment: The data is loaded with jQuery, so you'd need to use RSelenium to run the JavaScript before you can grab the HTML.

Comment: Scraping Forbes is a violation of their ToC https://www.forbes.com/terms and you obviously didn't even search SO for all the "scraping Forbes" questions.